# How can I target the element I'm hovering on and not all the list hierarchy in css

Tags: html, css

I would like to show the *"Icon"* when I hover on every item independently. The problem is that whenever I hover on a child item the parent is also showing its icon.

```css
.list {
  width: 150px;
  height: 19px;
}
.list >.item {
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  height: 30px;
}
.list .item .content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
.list .item .actions {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.list .item:hover .actions {
  visibility: visible;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ol class="list">
  <li class="item">
    <div class="content">
      <span>1- Hi...</span>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <span class="icon">Icon 1</span>
    </div>
    <ol class="list">
      <li class="item">
        <div class="content">
          <span>a- Hi 2...</span>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
          <span class="icon">Icon 2</span>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="content">
      <span>2- Hi 3...</span>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <span class="icon">Icon 3</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

How can I achieve this with CSS?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use Javascript? Cause there'd be a way you could do it using JS.

Comment: yea i mean, i wanted to solve it with CSS but if there is no chance on doing that i think i have to do it with JS.

Comment: One way is to add a class to the parent or child, and use different selectors for targeting parent and children

Comment: well you would have to give each item a specific id and then react on that. Let me try.

Comment: if you `hover` over a child, it means you `hover` over the parent also... not possible with CSS AFAIK...

Answer (score 1):

You can use an extra div as a wrapper for each item:

```css
.list {
  width: 150px;
  height: 19px;
}
.list >.item {
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  height: 30px;
}
.list .item .content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
.list .item .actions {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.list .item-wrapper:hover>.actions {
  visibility: visible;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ol class="list">
  <li class="item">
    <div class="item-wrapper">
      <div class="content">
        <span>1- Hi...</span>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <span class="icon">Icon 1</span>
      </div> 
    </div>
    <ol class="list">
      <li class="item">
        <div class="item-wrapper">
          <div class="content">
            <span>a- Hi 2...</span>
          </div>
          <div class="actions">
            <span class="icon">Icon 2</span>
          </div> 
        </div>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="item-wrapper">
      <div class="content">
        <span>2- Hi 3...</span>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <span class="icon">Icon 3</span>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks Peter i will give it a try. The problem is im using a library called NestableJS, so every time you try to append an item inside another, it creates another "item-wrapper" in the list, so it might get kind of messy to deal with CSS.